# How To show the array of object value after getting the index?

Tags: javascript

[image: localstorage array of object]
I have an array of object values in the local storage. I created some cards and in the onclick attribute, I pass the index to a function. Now I want to open a modal and show the values of each particular index position.

```
var updateModal = function (clickIndex) {
    alert(clickIndex.title)
    //here in the updateModal function I only get the result undefined.
```

**How to get the current index array of object value. What wrong with my code?**

Comment: How are you calling `updateModal`?  What does `console.log(clickIndex)` show you (I usually prefer `console.log` over `alert` for debugging)?

Comment: Please, no images of the data structure. Use text.

Comment: Use `clickIndex` as an index into the array. `cardsArray[clickIndex].title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to retrieve the items from localStorage first and Parse it, then use the index (clickIndex) you passed to pick the corresponding obj. in Code it so

```
  const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStrategy.getItem("The_name/var_you_used"));
  const myObj = cartItems[clickIndex];// this is what you want?
  return myObj;
```

Comment: At first, I get the local storage key and parse it then call it inside the modal function in that way `keyname[cardIndex].title` and it's working. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by it's not working? is it the modal not displaying or the object?